# Find the residues of all poles of $f(z) = \frac{ze^{iz}}{z^4 + 1}$ on the upper half of the complex plane

Tags: complex-analysis

I know that I should factor ${(z^4 + 1)}$ to
${(z^2 - i)(z^2 + i)}$ to find the poles of ${f(z)}$.

Consequently, using De Moivre's formula, the root in the upper half plane for ${(z^2 - i)}$ is:
$ {\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} + i \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}} $

And again, using De Moivre's formula, the root in the upper half plane for ${(z^2 + i)}$ is:
$ {\frac{-1}{\sqrt{2}} + i \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}} $

From here, since both poles are simple, I can calculate the residues for each using the formula: ${Res(f, c) = \frac{g(c)}{h'(c)}}$

But doing so gave me:

${Res(f, \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} + i \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}) =
\frac{(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} + i \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}) (e^{\frac{-1}{\sqrt{2}} + i \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}})}{-4i} 
} $

and

${Res(f, \frac{-1}{\sqrt{2}} + i \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}) =
\frac{(\frac{-1}{\sqrt{2}} + i \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}) (e^{\frac{-1}{\sqrt{2}} + i \frac{-1}{\sqrt{2}}})}{(4)(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} + i \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})} 
} $

Which I'm almost sure is incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

The poles in the upper half plane are at $e^{i\pi/4}$ and $e^{i3\pi/4}$.  The residues are given by

$$\lim_{z\to e^{i\pi/4}}(z-e^{i\pi/4})\frac{ze^{iz}}{z^4+1}\overbrace{=}^{LHR}\lim_{z\to e^{i\pi/4}}\frac{e^{iz}(1+iz)}{4z^3}$$

and

$$\lim_{z\to e^{i3\pi/4}}(z-e^{i3\pi/4})\frac{ze^{iz}}{z^4+1}\overbrace{=}^{LHR}\lim_{z\to e^{i3\pi/4}}\frac{e^{iz}(1+iz)}{4z^3}$$